# Pause HTML Output before response.redirect triggers

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

**NOTE:** I am not sure about title of the question so feel free to edit it.

I want to pause my page_laod event execution in .aspx page. following is my scenario.

Please note i have simplified the code for here my actual code is a bit different.

I have following Page1.aspx which aspx code is as follow.

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Page1.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Ass1.Page1" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <!------------------------- HTML code like title etc.. ------------------------->
    <script src='gatc.js' async defer></script>
    </HEAD>
    <body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

and Page1.aspx.cs's Page_Load event is as follow

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LogPDF(CatmastCat);
    Response.Redirect("/PDF/Pdf1.pdf");
}
```

As you can see i am not doing much in the page this page just transfers the request to particular PDF.

**My Problem is** recently our company have started implement GATC(Google analytic) on all pages and i have included GATC file on the page but actually since we have `Response.Redirect("/PDF/Pdf1.pdf");` in page_load itself browser directly redirects the page to PDF but what i need to do this browser should first execute `gatc.js` and then redirect to PDF so GATC can track hit on page1.aspx.

moreover i do not want to do changes in .cs file as i need to upload whole project(which is quiet big) DLL if i make any change in .cs file. so i want handle this by changing .aspx file only.

I already tried following but i think it is not woking

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Page1.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Ass1.Page1" %>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <!------------------------- HTML code ------------------------->
    <script src='gatc.js' async defer></script>
    </HEAD>
    /////////////// Change here
    <script runat="server">
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    </script>   
    /////////////// Change here
    <body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
        <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Please suggest me any solution for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the redirect, you just have to define your own version Page_Load in the .aspx file :

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogPDF(CatmastCat);
    }    
</script>
```

Then the processing has to be done client side. You just have to wait for the analytics call to complete.

It depends on your analytics version, see :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced

> **Setting the Hit Callback**
>
> In some cases, like when you track outbound links, you might want to
>   know when the tracker is done sending data.

it would lead to something like :

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/Page1.aspx',
  'hitCallback': function() {
    window.location='http://mydomain.com/PDF/Pdf1.pdf';
  }
});
```

or

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(function() {
        window.location='http://mydomain.com/PDF/Pdf1.pdf';
      });
```

Comment: thx for the help .. but how do i stop Response.Redirect("/PDF/Pdf1.pdf"); which is already there on server side in `page_load` event and i am not able to change it ..

Comment: +1 and Accepted your answer .. i got your point i will remove the whole .cs file refrence and will create it in aspx file itself